# Running a C++ program (containing TCP IP code) inside a linux container.

Tags: c++, linux, distributed

I am in the process of simulating a distributed system using LXC (LinuX Containers). I understand that there is a config file where i specify all the things like hostname etc. then i can start a container. But how do I run my code in that container. What are the steps?

**What I am trying to do:**

I need to create multiple containers interacting with each other using containers. I also need to write a 'master' container which will keep a tab on the various processes that are running inside the containers and also maintain a table of the interprocess communication messages that are happening ..

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for LXC?  Seems like that would be a fundamental feature.

Comment: @wallyk yes, I am (for the last hour) the problem is i cant find a straightforward explanation or steps to do it.

Comment: Did you see [this one](http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/lxc-linux-containers/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After attaching a address to the container, that address can be used for networking.